# C++, error while linking. Building with scons

Tags: c++, build, hyperlink, scons, wt

I try to run build example Wt project with scons, but for few hours I'm stuck.
When I compile it with command:

```
g++ -o hello hello.cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
  -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_random -lboost_regex
  -lboost_signals -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
  -lboost_program_options -lboost_date_time
```

(link to tutorial: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/wt.html#_hangman)
everything is ok, and I can run this simple example. 
But with my scons file:

```
env = Environment()

#       Add header search path
env.Append(CPPPATH = ['/usr/include', '/usr/local/include'])

#       Add compile-time flags
env.Append(CCFLAGS=[
#'-Wall','-g',
'-lwt', '-lwthttp',
'-lboost_random', '-lboost_regex', '-lboost_signals',
'-lboost_system', '-lboost_thread', '-lboost_filesystem',
'-lboost_program_options', '-lboost_date_time'
])

#       Add library search path
env.Append(LIBPATH = ['/usr/lib','/usr/local/lib', '/opt/lib'])

env.Program('hello',['exa.cc'])

#Program('exa.cc')
~
```

I can't and get following errors: http://pastebin.com/Ft2b62ie . 
Thanks for any answer.

Lukasz.

Comment: according to the error message you don't compile it with the libraries. see line 6 in the message.

Comment: when I move following paths: '/usr/lib','/usr/local/lib', '/opt/lib'to CPPPATH where are includes, I get the same error messages..

Comment: no i mean the libraries themselves. try to compile in terminal with the command you wrote above. `g++ -o hello hello.cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
  -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_random -lboost_regex
  -lboost_signals -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
  -lboost_program_options -lboost_date_time`

Comment: Yes, and I wrote that through command line, everything compiles properly. Problem is in my scons file, but I can't figure out why..

Comment: sorry i don't know scons, but why is every list in [] except `env.Program('hello',['exa.cc'])` -> hello? may it should be `env.Program(['hello','exa.cc'])`, or maybe you don't need exa.cc like `env.Program(['hello'])` or `env.Program('hello')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SConstruct should work for you:
The only difference is to place the libraries in the LIBS SCons Construction Variable and remove the '-l' from each, since its not necessary in SCons.

(Notice this is basically the same answer as user2093113, but with the libraries correctly specified: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555400/1158895)

```
env = Environment()

#       Add header search path
env.Append(CPPPATH = ['/usr/include', '/usr/local/include'])

#       Add compile-time flags
#env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-Wall','-g'])

# libraries to link against
# Notice you dont need the '-l', since SCons is platform independent
env.Append(LIBS=[
  'wt', 'wthttp',
  'boost_random', 'boost_regex', 'boost_signals',
  'boost_system', 'boost_thread', 'boost_filesystem',
  'boost_program_options', 'boost_date_time'
])

#       Add library search path
env.Append(LIBPATH = ['/usr/lib','/usr/local/lib', '/opt/lib'])

# Compile and link the binary
env.Program('hello',['exa.cc'])
```

Answer (score -2):

Your linker flags shouldn't be appended to `CCFLAGS` but `LIBS` instead.

```
env.Append(LIBS=[
'-lwt', '-lwthttp',
'-lboost_random', '-lboost_regex', '-lboost_signals',
'-lboost_system', '-lboost_thread', '-lboost_filesystem',
'-lboost_program_options', '-lboost_date_time'
])
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to specify libs with SCons, Im surprised it didnt give an error or warning of some sort. The "-l" flag should not be specified, SCons adds those.